# Solve the following autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that the following ode has a maximum of one solution.
>
> $$x'(t) = |x(t)| +\sin(x^2(t)+t^2) \quad \text{with} \quad  x(0)=0$$
>
> and that this solution satisfy $x(t)\leq  e^t-1$ for $t \geq 0$

We got the hint: compare with  $x'(t)= |x(t)|+1$

I solved the ODE of the hint and got 
for $x(t) \geq 0 $  the solution $ x(t)=c_{1}e^t-1  ,c_{1} \in \mathbb{R}$

for $x(t) < 0 $  the solution $ x(t)=c_{2}e^{-t}+1  ,c_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$

Now  I´m not sure what to do. I know that if $c_{1}=1$ I get $x(t)\leq  e^t-1$ for $t \geq 0$.

What have i to do next? I have problems to show Lipschitz-continuity, because i cant find an L. I need some help.

Comment: I edited your formatting and fixed one bracket, is this ok?

Comment: Are you sure this ODE is autonomous? There's $t$ explicitly there

Comment: We called this in class autonomous ODE because we only can compare with ODE´s which we can solve

Comment: My guess is: you've got to use the fact that $|\sin (x^2+t^2)| \leq 1$, so the more simple equation is kind of a limiting case of that

Comment: And then I only have to show Lipschitz-continuity?

Comment: I don't know, it's been a long time since I had to solve problems like that

Comment: You only get local Lipschitz continuity due to the quadratic factor. Show that separately, for the abs term with the inverse triangle inequality, for the sine term using some mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $f(t,x)=|x|+\sin(x^2+t^2)$ you get the bound for the difference of the right side under variations of the state variable as
\begin{align}
|f(t,y)-f(t,x)|&\le\Bigl||y|-|x|\Bigr|+2\sin(\frac{|y^2-x^2|}2)\cos(t^2+\frac{x^2+y^2}2)
\\&
\le|y-x|+|y-x|\,|y+x|
\end{align}
so that on the region $|x|\le R$ one gets a Lipschitz constant $L=1+2R$. Until the solution leaves such a region, you get uniqueness. For a global result you need to exclude divergence to infinity in finite time, which the bound on the solution delivers.